# json getting attribute in position 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

so if i have the following json

```
{
"data": {
    "sectionList": {
        "section124": [{
                "a": "test",
                "b": "test",
                "c": "test",
                "d": "test",
                "e": "test2013-04-14"
            }, {
                "a": "test",
                "b": "test",
                "c": "test",
                "d": "test",
                "e": "test2013-04-14"
            }
        ]
    },
    "section00824": [
        [{
                "a": "test",
                "b": "test",
                "c": "test",
                "d": "test",
                "e": "test2013-04-14"
            }, {
                "a": "test",
                "b": "test",
                "c": "test",
                "d": "test",
                "e": "test2013-04-14"
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

}

and i do a ajax get on it within my code and have a callback that returns result i need to know what the first section is called

i know I can do this:

```
return result.data.sectionList.section124;
```

but the problem is I dont know what that name is as it can change every time

i tried

```
return result.data.sectionList.*;
return result.data.sectionList[0];
```

but they are not allowed

any ideas?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have only one section, then you can get its name by doing something like `Object.keys(result.data.sectionList)[0]`. However, if you have more than one section and you want the first, then you can't do that from the `result` object since objects in JavaScript don't preserve key ordering.

Comment: could i do this.. var section = "result.data.sectionList." + Object.keys(result.data.sectionList)[0];
   alert(section);
   
            return section;

Comment: No, you would do something like `result.data.sectionList[Object.keys(result.data.sectionList)[0]]` or make it more neat, `var key = Object.keys(result.data.sectionList)[0]; return result.data.sectionList[key]`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the for each loop to iterate in sectionList like this:

```
for each (var item in result.data.sectionList) {
  //ur stuff here
}
```

and also you can use a normal for loop like this:

```
for(var item in result.data.sectionList){
  var itemValue= result.data.sectionList[item ];
  //ur stuff here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its a `key` `value` pair. Ordering cannot be guaranteed.

You can do `for(key in result.data.sectionList){}` to get the keys and return what you want.